# How to show logs from Android Library project?

Tags: android

My project is marked as a Library.

```
public class ToolboxActivity extends ToolboxBaseActivity{
    private final String TAG = "ToolboxActivity";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
}
```

When I run my main project and go to this above code's activity, I do not see any logs. How do I make it so I can see the logs?

[image: Android Library Project]

Comment: There's no reason logs from a library class wouldn't fire. Are you sure you are subclassing this specific class and calling super.onCreate()?

Comment: I am sure I going to this activity.

Comment: What is the string Assignment for `TAG`?  Use that as a filter in your logcat view.  Window > View > other > logcat (or switch to debug perspective)

Comment: Updated the code. But yes, I have already tried that. I did am trying tag:ToolboxActivity but I do not get anything.

Comment: Attempt to launch the application in debug mode and set a breakpoint to see if it catches from whatever class that extends your `ToolboxActivity`

Comment: Tried the debug, but the debugger doesn't catch it. Eclipse doesn't ask to change to debugger perspective.

Comment: Okay, restarting eclipse fixed the debugger and logging issue.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting eclipse fixed the issue.